# Regex. Match any number from 1 - 365

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

We are using a RegEx Validator to validate an input from a textbox.

The current RegEx expression checks if the current number is between the range of 1 - 999.

We just inherited this code and we need to change the range from 999 to just 365. In short, we need to write a regex to check if the input is between 1 - 365.

Of course, we can just use a RangeValidator or a custom validator. But we don't want to do that because we don't want to introduce a "significant" change.

Thanks!

EDIT:

We should also catch this following patterns:
001 for 1
019 for 19

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using regular expressions is certainly not the best way to validate integer ranges, but here you go:

```
 ^([1-9][0-9]?|[12][0-9][0-9]|3[0-5][0-9]|36[0-5])$

[1-9][0-9]?     matches    1 -  99
[12][0-9][0-9]  matches  100 - 299
3[0-5][0-9]     matches  300 - 359
36[0-5]         matches  360 - 365
```

EDIT: With leading zeros (also matches strings like 00000000321):

```
 ^0*([1-9][0-9]?|[12][0-9][0-9]|3[0-5][0-9]|36[0-5])$
```

Comment: Does this cover single digit numbers?

Comment: Sure. [1-9][0-9]? covers 1-99.

Comment: This is failing for 100 upwards. :(

Comment: @lan: I forgot to use parantheses. Please try again using the updated pattern – it should work now!

Answer (score 5):

Mind the gap, ehm leap year. :-)

Comment: +1 ... Well, 1-365 could be *anything*, really. Why do you think it is for validating days in a year? ;-)

Comment: 365 seems to be a rather random number is it is not the number of days in a "normal" year...

Answer (score 2):

you really don't want to use regex for that, you should just use /^\d{1,3}$/ and validate the number as being 1..365

as for just regex:

```
SNIP
```

ferdinands is fine :)

Comment: This is more sensible approach.

Answer (score 1):

Little addition to Ferdinand's regexp for catching leading zeros:

```
^([0]{0,2}[1-9]|[0]?[1-9][0-9]|[12][0-9][0-9]|3[0-5][0-9]|36[0-5])$

[0]{0,2}[1-9]  - catches 001, 01, 1...
[0]?[1-9][0-9] - catches 010, 10...
```

Notice, it does not catch 0234 or 0019

Comment: That is not really a problem because the textbox only allows for 3 characters. :)